# Summernote edit not displaying scroll bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, summernote

I am using summernote in a bootstrap modal and set it up as follows:

```
 $('.summernote').summernote({
     toolbar: [
        ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear','fontname']],
        ['color', ['color']],
        ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
        ['height', ['height']],
        ['style', ['style']],
        ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],  
        ['misc', ['fullscreen','undo','redo']],
        ['table', ['table']]
    ]
    });
```

The problems is that no scroll bar appears when I am entering text into the edit area and go below the bottom of the edit area as in:

[image]

What is needed to have the scroll bars appear and constrain the text to stay within the lines?

Comment: figure it out?  Having same issue.

Comment: It's working for me. I don't remember what I changed. Sorry. I took a look at the code and there's nothing obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation for Summernote](http://summernote.org/jsduck/#!/api/$.summernote) says:

> height : String/Number (optional)
>
> set editor height (e.g. 300px)
>
> Defaults to: null

So, solution is:

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
    height: '300px',
    toolbar: [
        ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear','fontname']],
        ['color', ['color']],
        ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
        ['height', ['height']],
        ['style', ['style']],
        ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],  
        ['misc', ['fullscreen','undo','redo']],
        ['table', ['table']]
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this on my CSS:

```
    .note-editable.panel-body {
            overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

it works for me

Answer (score -1):

you may would like to try this

```
.bootstrap-modal-selector {
   overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: No effect. I'm sure summernote overrides.